# Can I swap 2 xbox accounts crossed over with epicgames accounts?

Tags: xbox-one, fortnite-battle-royale, epic-games-launcher

When activating a game on epic games, it is a little unclear what you are doing...

Hence as a noob and a Dad, trying to setup my kids looks simple.
But what they don't tell you when you link your xbox account is that you need to confirm(twice) who you are playing the game as and who you are signed in as in your pc browser, and because I am the dad I am signing in/out back a forwards to setup each child as each child plays the game.

So this is what the result was
Dad's xbox account got linked to Child1's Epic Games Account, because when I did the activate on PC I happened to be signed in as Child1, this permantently link Dads Xbox to Child1's EpicGames
Then Activating Child1's Xbox Account, I could not as it was already linked, so without thinking I signed in again as myself, which caused the opposite link.

- Dad   Xbox <--> Child EG
- Child Xbox <--> Dad   EG

How to I swap these over?

Answer (score 1):

Epic Games will tell you "It cannot be done they are permanently linked."
Politically they are correct. Technically they are wrong.
The reason is something to do with their policies.
I did not try to prove them wrong politically.

Technically all I did was (on EpicG) swap my sons username and email address to my username and email address and vice versa. Luckily we had the same games purchased on our accounts, only thing my son got was a friend on his account.

Now this is really only possible if they are new accounts like ours were, most gamers will have already bought games on Epic and on Xbox and then their child comes along, but if that is the case you probably would have already learned this lesson prior.

The other option is scrap the epic games acount and start again.